# m2e and project metadata files

Tags: eclipse, maven, version-control, m2e

I'm used to other IDEs such as Visual Studio which keep project structure on some metadata files. I'm using Eclipse right now and I used m2e eclipse to import a maven project. afaik Eclipse only gets source/resource files from pom.xml (or maven default directories if none is specified) and create the project tree.

Therefore, i think that, if I have the code and Eclipse configuration files (.project, .classpath) in a repository and I update code directory structure, no Eclipse files will be updated and therefore I don't need to update Eclipse files in the repository.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, if you use m2e (recent versions) and a SCM (Git, Svn, CVS, etc.), you don't need to commit the Eclipse configuration files to the repository.
These main files are :

- `.project`
- `.classpath`
- `.settings/`

There is a [good example on GitHub](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/Eclipse.gitignore) of a `.gitignore` file which shows what files in Eclipse you don't need to commit.

**EDIT :**

To regenerate Eclipse project files, you can either :

1. Import > Existing Maven Projects : needed eclipse files are created
2. Import > Checkout Projects from SVN (or CVS, GIT, etc.) ..... if needed : Convert to Maven project
3. Use CLI maven-eclipse-plugin with `mvn eclipse:eclipse` ([Goal](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/eclipse-mojo.html)) (not recommended if using m2e)

Comment: So I'll store no Eclipse files in the repository? If so, how a new developer will open the Eclipse project of the application? He'll be forced to import Maven project again? I wanted that a new dev didn't need to know how to import Maven projects, he should only open a project and work in the code.

Comment: There is another discussion about whether to store Eclipse configuration files in SCM or not : [Is it a good practice to include Eclipse project files in with sources in SCM?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417243/is-it-a-good-practice-to-include-eclipse-project-files-in-with-sources-in-scm)

Comment: I edited my answer to explain when Eclipse files are generated.

Answer (score 3):

Correct, you don't need to save the .project and ,class path files in a repository.  The m2e commands "Update Project Configuration" and "Update Project Dependencies" will correct those files, respectively, once you've retrieved the rest of the source from the repository.